# Add Actors to existing Akka Cluster Shard

Tags: akka, cluster-computing, sharding

Is there a way to create Actors and add them to existing Cluster Shard in Akka ?
1) Create/Start Cluster Shard when App starts
2) Create Actor for each API request
3) Add them to the existing shard

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Cluster Sharding, it will take care of the actor lifecycle for you. I.e. you don't create an actor, you ask the `ShardRegion` to give you an actor for an ID and you will get one (placed in an existing shard). So yes, you could create a new ID on every API request and have the `ShardRegion` give you a (new) actor for it.

Cluster Sharding is described in some detail on http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-sharding.html , that should clear things up a little.